# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException in NumberPicker

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception, android-number-picker

In pre launch reports for Android, I am getting the following error. While watching the recording it looks like when the bot selects a value it crashes but I cannot replicate the issue. Let me know if you need more information. How can I resolve this error?

```
07-27 01:48:35.765: E/AndroidRuntime(14892): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (4 ... 4) ends beyond length 0
07-27 01:48:35.765: E/AndroidRuntime(14892):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1096)
07-27 01:48:35.765: E/AndroidRuntime(14892):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:671)
07-27 01:48:35.765: E/AndroidRuntime(14892):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:664)
07-27 01:48:35.765: E/AndroidRuntime(14892):    at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:76)
07-27 01:48:35.765: E/AndroidRuntime(14892):    at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:87)
07-27 01:48:35.765: E/AndroidRuntime(14892):    at android.widget.EditText.setSelection(EditText.java:98)
07-27 01:48:35.765: E/AndroidRuntime(14892):    at android.widget.EditText.performAccessibilityActionInternal(EditText.java:138)
07-27 01:48:35.765: E/AndroidRuntime(14892):    at android.view.View.performAccessibilityAction(View.java:8892)
07-27 01:48:35.765: E/AndroidRuntime(14892):    at android.widget.NumberPicker$AccessibilityNodeProviderImpl.performAction(NumberPicker.java:2472)
```

The number picker is set up this way

```
    numberPicker.setMaxValue(stringArrayOfCurrentPickerViewArray.length - 1);
    numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
    numberPicker.setDisplayedValues(stringArrayOfCurrentPickerViewArray);
    numberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
    numberPicker.setSaveFromParentEnabled(false);
    numberPicker.setSaveEnabled(true);
```

And when a value is selected

```
            int row = numberPicker.getValue();
            if (row != 0) {
                if (row > 0 && row <= stringArrayOfCurrentPickerViewArray.length - 1) {
                    textField.setText(stringArrayOfCurrentPickerViewArray[row]);
                }
            }
```

Comment: I guess its something to do with  numberPicker.setMaxValue(stringArrayOfCurrentPickerViewArray.length - 1); this line, you're cutting the last character yet trying to access it.

Comment: numberPicker.setSaveEnabled(false);

Comment: I have tried both of these suggestions, however I am still running into the issue in pre launch reports.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue on some devices. Have you found the reason for this and a solution?